# How to make a formula to sum values by month?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I have a database with products ordered by day. How do I make an excel formula to sum the values by month so that autofill sums each month when I drag down?
I want this formula in a different sheet and I cannot make any more columns in this sheet. 
Example:

```
Col A       Col B
5/1/2014    411
5/2/2014    332
5/3/2014    247
5/4/2014    369
5/5/2014    780
5/6/2014    577
5/7/2014    653
5/8/2014    848
5/9/2014    925
5/10/2014   911
5/11/2014   444
5/12/2014   327
5/13/2014   440
5/14/2014   503
5/15/2014   613
5/16/2014   753
5/17/2014   875
5/18/2014   404
5/19/2014   628
5/20/2014   776
5/21/2014   829
5/22/2014   505
5/23/2014   515
5/24/2014   703
5/25/2014   511
5/26/2014   747
5/27/2014   707
5/28/2014   782
5/29/2014   101
5/30/2014   113
5/31/2014   283
```

Comment: Is this data in two columns, at least? Is that what the colon means?

Comment: Yes, it's in two columns. There are more columns with other products to the right as well.

Comment: You could just use a pivot table. Put the Date in the Row labels section, then right click and group by Months and Years. Add Column B to the Values section of the pivot table. Any time new data is added, refreshing the pivot table will update the table.

Comment: True, a pivot table is so much more efficient. In my particular case though there is already a spreadsheet where the formula was inputted manually each month and I would really like to have a formula with autofill where I can drag down.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the dates are in column A and the values are in column B, you can use the following formula for the January subtotal.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH($A$1:$A$1000)=ROWS(A$1:A1))*$B$1:$B$1000)
```

Filling down will get the subtotal for the subsequent months.

**Explanation:**

`$A$1:$A$1000` are all your dates. Change this reference to match your specific sheet and number of rows.

`MONTH($A$1:$A$1000)` generates an array of numbers representing the month of each date, e.g. your sample data would generate `{5, 5, ..., 5}`.

`ROWS(A$1:A1)` is a trick to get the formula to check the subsequent month when filled down. For the first entry, this will equal 1 (the month number for January), for the next it will equal 2 (the month number for February).

`MONTH($A$1:$A$1000)=ROWS(A$1:A1)` generates an array of Boolean values indicating whether each month falls in the specified month, e.g., for your sample data the array would be `{FALSE, FALSE, ..., FALSE}` because none of the dates fall in January.

`MONTH($A$1:$A$1000)=ROWS(A$1:A1)*$B$1:$B$1000` pairwise multiplies the values from column B by the array of Boolean values. Thus, data from non-matching months return 0 and matches return the value from B.

`SUMPRODUCT` adds the values from this array, giving you the total only for the month specified.

Comment: This formula returns 0:

=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH($A$1435:$A$1464)=ROWS(A$1435:A1435))*E1435:E1464)

Did I mess up somewhere?

Comment: If that's for the data above, then it's as expected since none of the dates are in January.

Comment: The full document has all the months for the past few years so it should not be zero. Regardless, how is it getting January data though?

Comment: The argument of MONTH should be all your data. The range from E should be of corresponding size.

Comment: I just noticed I left off some `$`s from the formula. Please see my edited answer and update your formula accordingly.

Comment: I don't understand the formula. I'm trying to understand how it works and I can't figure it out. Maybe if you break it down for me I can figure it out?